# Does $.each not function on a json node if the node has only one child. Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

So I am trying to iterate through a json object, but I don't know if it will have one child or many. I am using the **$.each** jquery function with coffee script like so:

```
$.each data.searchresults.response.results.result, (i) ->
  count = i + 1
  console.log data.searchresults.response.result.address.street
```

Now this works if the "result" node has two instances; however, when it only has one instance it doesn't work. My question is, am I writing the $.each function in a sub optimal way and/or two should I just check how many result nodes exist then decide to either loop or just access the node?

JSON With **Two**: http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz1dj9f5y35l7_agge7&address=3925%20edwardsville%20galena%20road&citystatezip=47122

JSON with **One**: http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz1dj9f5y35l7_agge7&address=206%20Plum%20lake%20drive&citystatezip=47172

No error when running multiple result node, but here is the error when running it with only one result node:

*TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.searchresults.response.results.result[i].address.street')*

Comment: `json node` sounded a bit fishy. That's XML not JSON

Comment: The looping should work fine for any number of nodes/elements - if theres 0, it wont loop, if theres more, it will loop however many. Make sure the result is in the same format because "$.each" expects an object or array, and your results are most likely an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue I was having (stupid I know) was that inside the .each function I was using the full object path with [i] to access the correct iteration of the object.

So instead of using this `console.log data.searchresults.response.result[i].address.street`

I adjusted the script to look like this:

```
$.each data.searchresults.response.results.result, (i,result) ->
  count = i + 1
  console.log result.address.street
```